# Is it a good practice to create a separated partition for a grub2 loader?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, grub, multi-boot, boot-partition

I want install Debian 6. I want have a `grub2` as a boot loader.

I read, that creating a separated primary `/boot` partition for the kernel (with read-only access) is a good practice. Is it also a good practice to make a separated primary `/grub` partition?

- What could it be useful for?
- What are the problems caused by such a partition scheme?
- Are some specific information I need to know, if I will install the same configuration to a VPS?
- What if I use LVM for `/`, `/home` and other partitions?

If it is a good practice or even just not a bad idea - should the `/grub` partition better be placed before the `/boot` one (at the beginning of the disk)?

HDD 100Gb

Answer (score 0):

Not that I've ever seen. `/grub` needs to be mounted at `/boot/grub` anyway, but really I think a separate partition just for the grub files themselves is something like overkill.

Consider also that when you boot, grub expects its files to be under the partition you set as root (e.g. (hd0,0)). Of course, you can fstab mount your grub partition beneath your boot partition, but that doesn't help while you're in Grub's stage 2 mode and none of that has been done yet.

Most likely it's possible to work around that with a suitable configuration file (Grub is fairly mutable) but I'd consider maintaining that setup more trouble than the result is worth.

If you use LVM for any system-critical directories (`/`,`/usr`,`/var`, etc) you're going to need an initial ram filesystem which contains the LVM tools to turn on those volume groups and hand over booting to the kernel - otherwise your kernel will panic on boot because it can't find its root device, or a key file it needed out of `/usr`.

In summary, I think you're just giving yourself a headache with this plan.